# Designing a posts database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I need to create a database for an app which shows posts by different authors.

Some of the necessary columns are:

```
id (INT)
url (TEXT)
content (TEXT)
date (TEXT)
author_username (TEXT)
author_fullname (TEXT)
author_avatar_url (TEXT)
author_url (TEXT)
```

Now, each post by an author can be from different feeds like `timeline`, `favorites`, etc with a **different unique id** for each feed while the other columns remain the same.

For example:

```
id   | url     | content | date |... | username | fullname | avatar | url
-----+---------+---------+------+----+----------+ ---------+--------+--------
 123 | foo.com | xyz     | 2018 |... |  foo     | foobar   | avatarurl.com | foobar.com  <---- Feed 1 
1592 | foo.com | xyz     | 2018 |... |  foo     | foobar   | avatarurl.com | foobar.com  <---- Feed 2
 148 | foo.com | xyz     | 2018 |... |  foo     | foobar   | avatarurl.com | foobar.com  <---- Feed 3
```

So to remove the redundancy, I decided on having three tables as follows -

**Author** table:

```
username | fullname | avatar_url | url
```

- `username` is the PK

**Posts** table:

```
internal_id | url | content | date | ... | author_username
```

- `internal_id` is auto-incrementing and is the PK
- `author_username` is the FK referencing `Author.username`

**Feeds** table:

```
post_id | feed | post_internal_id
```

- `post_id` is the PK
- `post_internal_id` is the FK referencing `Posts.internal_id`

I don't have much experience with database design which is why I want to know if this design is correct. Can it be improved in any way? Some of the queries to be performed on the db are fetching all posts from a particular source, updating a column in the posts table for a particular `post_id`, fetching the author data using the `post_id`.

Comment: So you get posts from different sources, like different servers, and it happens that two or three such sources report the same post? What exactly is `source`? A fixed number of devices, such as 'SERVER1', 'SERVER2', 'SERVER3'? Or an infinite number of origins, such as "From Tom's computer on Feb 2, 2017, 08:00", "Found on Google when searching for <black, box>", "Sent by George@web.com via email"?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Probably shouldn't have called it that but the user has a bunch of feeds like `timeline`, `favorites` etc. The sources are these feeds. So a post in the timeline can be marked as favorite which will put it in both the feeds and yet will have a different id.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect a feeds table that is not related to a post. With the same set of feeds for all users:

```
feeds(feed_id, feed_name)
```

Then you'd still have:

```
users(username, fullname, avatar_url, url)
posts(post_id, content, date, username)
```

And then the table linking posts to user feeds:

```
post_feeds(post_id, feed_id)
```

Well, you can work with single IDs or composite keys, but it should be something along those lines :-)

Comment: All users have the same set of feeds. What are `user_id` and `post_id` columns?

Comment: Well, okay, I just used technical IDs in all tables. You can replace `user_id` with `username` in all tables if you like that better. As to post_id: Every table gets its own ID. A post gets an ID we can refer to in `post_user_feeds`. Otherwise, how could we build a table that lists posts with their feeds?

Comment: As all users have the same feeds, you can do with the feeds table alone with no need of a user_feeds table. Then change `user_feed_id` in `post_user_feeds` to `feed_id` and change the table's name from `post_user_feeds` to `post_feeds` to get this more readable. Well, I'll update my answer accordingly...

Comment: So the `post_id` is the `id`? If so, then what is `feed_id`? Because neither the feeds nor the authors have an id, only the posts do.

Comment: I thought you are in the process of designing the database? And if there is an ID that represents the post only, what else is this than the post ID? As to feed IDs: There is a certain set of possible feeds. Store them in a table; give them IDs. Now use these IDs to link your posts to feeds.

Comment: Is the feed id necessary? Can the table only contain the feed name and a FK to the posts table?

Comment: Yes it can. It only feels kind of incomplete to deal with an entity `feeds` and not have a table for this. With a table you'd have the name 'favorites' in only one place, so you'd avoid typos like 'favvorites' in some records; and if you want to rename the feed to 'favs' someday, again that's only a change in one place instead of possibly thousands of records. But yes, you *can* do without a feeds table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164099/discussion-between-jl4-and-thorsten-kettner).